# Agreed to work beyond notice period, now I've changed my mind? (UK)

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I have resigned from my job with a 1 week notice period, I agreed to work a few days beyond the week's notice but have changed my mind. Am I contractually obligated to work to the agreed end date?

The company had me amend my resignation letter to reflect the extended notice period, but my contract only states I must give 1 week.

Comment: You amended the letter. That's a contract. Talk to your company about changing it. Theoretically, I would guess that you can still leave after a week's notice, if you submit a new notice now... but I'm not sure ow much that would save you, and I AM NOT A LAWYER.

Comment: Why have you changed your mind?  Will a few days really make that much of an impact on you?

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of the legal implications of the situation, it is VERY bad form to go back on such an agreement. It's always in your best interest to make your departure as clean and painless as you can make it for all parties concerned. Even if you don't ever want to come work for them again, if you need something from them (like a reference for instance) then your last days will often determine whether or not they will help you. Many people will feel that the last days you work for an employer is when you show your true colours, so use this as a chance to impress your former co-workers, manager(s) and boss(es).

Comment: Couldn't agree more - you made an agreement and going back on it in such a short space of time comes accross as incredibly unprofessional.

Comment: 100% agree. If you've agreed to something, then don't change your mind. This is a good life skill :)